# Do dead corpses in town bypass town defenses?

Tags: die2nite

If we have say, 4 corpses in town, and sufficient defenses for the next day, do the 4 corpses in town get added to those attacking the town or will they potentially kill/terrorize 4 citizens?

Mostly trying to decide if its worth the water/AP to dispose of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never experienced it, but it's to my understanding that it's the second one and that they do bypass the town's defenses and terrorize people that would then only have their house defense and defensive items in their chest to save them. The first one where they get added to the attack is if you throw them out of town.

Because of people liking their brains, disposing of them is worth your AP or water in almost every situation. The only time that it wouldn't would probably be if you don't have enough defenses to protect against the attack anyway, but watering them would still help there, and you would pretty much be doomed then anyway.

EDIT: I found it in the Die2Nite help under "The Attack of the Hordes" now:

> #### Phase 1 : The Return of the Living Dead
>
> All the citizens who died in the town the night before and whose corpse has not been destroyed or dumped in the desert will rise again ! As they are already within the town walls, they'll do untold damage !
>
> The dead who have been dumped in the desert will attack the town as one of the Horde.

Comment: that makes sense, can someone confirm this?

Comment: I found it in the Die2Nite wiki just now.

Comment: the one thing I think is incorrect: a corpse in town ignores home defences, so if there is 1 corpse in town when the attack happanes at least 1 player will be killed.  The same for when a corpse is dragged outside instead of watered, when the zombies get in any corpses dragged outside ignore home defence and kill 1 person each.  I am not 100% sure on this, could use some confrimation from somebody who has experienced, the english wiki's are full of uncorrect info however so I wouldnt use that as a source.